# Is there any situations where real exchange rate positively impacts on national imports?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, international-trade, exchange-rates

I'm working on a gravity model analysing the factors that affect national imports, and the results showed that the real exchange rate (real exchange rate between local currency and foreign currency) has a positive effect on national imports and it is even statistically significant.

Could you please tell me any situations where this can make sense?
Thanks.

Comment: In your question you are ambiguous about the sign of the effect. You should definitely expect negative significant effect of real exchange rate on imports

Comment: @1muflon1 I don't know how to explain this. Could you tell me how real exchange rate can have a negative effect on imports?

Comment: when real exchange falls exports become relatively more expensive

Comment: @1muflon1 oops sorry I made a mistake. I meant positive... sorry. Can you give me an explanation for this situation please?

Comment: Think real exchange rates in terms of purchasing powers